# mouseenter / mouseleave event fired when moving from shape to circle in kinetic group

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I have Kinetic group which contains custom shape and circle.
Mouseenter and mouseleave events are specified on **group** level.
When I move from shape to circle and vice versa events are fired, which (I guess) is not correct as I am all the time above group.

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 400,
    height: 300
  });
  var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var group = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 100,
    y: 40,
    listening: true
  });

      var square = new Kinetic.Shape({
         sceneFunc: function(context) {
           context.beginPath();
           context.moveTo(50, 50);
           context.lineTo(150, 50);
           context.lineTo(150, 100);
           context.lineTo(50, 100);
           context.lineTo(50, 50);
           context.closePath();
           // KineticJS specific context method
           context.fillStrokeShape(this);
         },
         fill: 'red',
         stroke: 'black',
         strokeWidth: 4
       });

      var circle =  new Kinetic.Circle();
        circle.x( 75 );
        circle.y( 75);
        circle.fill( 'LightGray' );
        circle.stroke( 'Gray' );
        circle.strokeWidth( 2 );
        circle.strokeEnabled( true );
        circle.listening(true);
        circle.draggable( true );
        circle.radius( 10 );

      group.add(square);
      group.add(circle);

  group.on( 'mouseenter', function( evt ) {         
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } );

  group.on( 'mouseleave', function( evt ) {         
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    } );
  shapesLayer.add(group);
  stage.add(shapesLayer); `
```

See mouse pointer in example here: http://jsfiddle.net/69K59/2/

Answer (score 0):

Mouse movements on the group itself do not trigger mouse events.

Mouse events on nodes (shapes,circles,etc) **do trigger** mouse events.

That's why you get leave+enter when moving from the circle to the rect.

Comment: So why there is a listening parameter on the group ? According what you have said it has no real impact ...

Comment: group.listening(false) is useful in turning off listening for all contained nodes with one command.  Remember that Kinetic.Groups are extensions of Containers, not extensions of Nodes.  Groups allow operations to be done on sets of nodes. ;-)